# Having trouble starting .NET MVC project with Web Api integrated

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on integrating an existing Web Api project into a .NET MVC (4.5.2) project. So far, I've copied in the WebApiConfig.cs (but am not yet referencing it from Global.asax.cs), as well as some exception logging/handlers from the Web Api project. I've also added a few required references - `Microsoft.Data.OData`, an updated version of `Newtonsoft.Json`, `System.Web.Http.Formatting`, `System.Web.Cors`, `System.Web.Http.Cors` and `System.Web.Http`.

The application doesn't start - no breakpoints in the handlers I added are hit, nor is `Application_Start()` ever hit. I'm having trouble nailing down the root cause here and am unsure how to debug this further.

Comment: Do you see any exception in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your Global.asax.cs

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
}
```

then from there, you should be able to put a breakpoint on your global asax.cs and figure out what's the error.

Comment: Added that, but it doesn't seem to hit that either.

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause. As a part of installation of one of the packages, this was added to the `<system.webServer><handlers>` section of my web.config.

```
<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
<remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

The application at least starts now - we'll see if it presents problems when I finish fully integrating the Web Api project.